# Выравнивание 2х div'ов, относительно ширины страницы

Tags: css

Приветствую

Можно ли записать 2 div'а в одну строку так, что бы ширина первого была фиксированная, а ширина второго динамическая?

**[Тыц](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLu7/)**

С верху 2 дива, второй съезжает. Аналогично давам с низу таблица, там вторая ячейка меняет ширину относительно страницы. Вот могут ли дивы так же изменять ширину?

p.s. и чтоб меня застрелили в затылок, за вопрос вечером

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
    <div>
      <div class="one">hashcode</div>
      <div class="two">hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode hashcode</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one {
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:#DDFFFF;
}

.two {
    background-color:#FFDDFF;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-left: 102px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3dLu7/3/

Comment: float: left;//оно самое!